# How to add one specific row in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
structure(list(time = c("Time1", "Time2", "Time3", "Time4", "Time5", "Time6"
), DASS_stress = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 18, 26, NA_real_, 
4), DASS_anx = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 12, 6, 
NA_real_, 0), DASS_depr = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 4, 
6, NA_real_, 2)), row.names = c("3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8"), class = "data.frame")
```

Call it DASS_pre. I am trying to create a table with mean, standard deviation, and range for DASS_stress, DASS_anx, and DASS_depr. I have already filtered the data and I can get the values I need using this follow code:

```
mean(DASS_pre$DASS_stress, na.rm=TRUE)
SD(DASS_pre$DASS_stress)
range(DASS_pre$DASS_stress, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But I want to add a row called Stress and have the values Mean, SD, and Range but I realized the way I'm doing it I would have to name each value and add it into a matrix or DF separately for each variable (e.g. DASS_stress, DASS_anx, and DASS_depr). Is there an easier way to do this for all three so I won't have to go back and name each value separately as I run the mean, SD, and range for each variable? The way I'm doing it right now is surely going to take a lot of the same steps.

Comment: `range` gives two values and not one

Answer (score 1):

If we want to get the statistics for multiple columns, use `lapply` or `sapply`

```
lapply(DASS_pre[-1], function(x) list(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
           sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), range(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```